# Unwanted behaviour of a html template when in use with django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I downloaded a free html/css/js template and wanted to run it on django. After fixing some of the directories for static files I managed to get it running.

My problem is that some of the sliding elements are unusually extended and instead of being let's say 50px in height, they cover half of the page with nothing but blank. These elements also behave weirdly.

If I inspect the element, for some reason all the proportions go back to normal, however when I click and drag the inspect element window up and down, the weirdly behaving elements extend and retract with the inspect element window. I'm relatively new to all this so I'm not even sure whether I should be looking through the html, css or the js files in order to find out why it does that. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Edit: Also if use the zoom option in firefox to scale the website down, for example to 30%, the same elements don't scale down, they keep on extending.

So far I tried to delete the template that I used and reload it along with the static files, but still no success.

```
html index is here `https://pastebin.com/raw/TPUMpr9D`
```

[This is what it looks like if I just run the html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJeev.jpg)

[Here I'm running it on django and you can see the elements extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYcGt.jpg)

[Opening the inspect element window fixes the proportions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM7jg.jpg)

[Moving the inspect element window also moves the extended elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOKoQ.jpg)

[Trying to scale or zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrZyJ.jpg)

Comment: can you post the template code

Comment: @ger.s.brett Which one would you like? Here's the html index if that's the one you want https://pastebin.com/raw/TPUMpr9D